# How to take runtime input in selenium while automation testing?

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests

I'm trying to take data from user at run time while automating a Webapplication. I have searched a lot but I couldn't find anything. I have tried this method. (code mentioned below)

```
Scanner scanner_user = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your Email or Phone : ");
    String user = scanner_user.nextLine();
    System.out.println("our otp is " + user.toString());
```

but It doesn't work . it ask to enter data in console but it says read only view. please help me how can I take data at runtime.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code can you show us the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below in this scenario user is passing the `password` manually through console.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String password;   
                System.out.println("Please Enter the user password :: ");
                password= br.readLine();  
                driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("password");
```